# How to get clicked element in jQuery Selectable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery selectable, which having following html

```
<div class="selectable ui-selectable" id="timeslot">
<span data-y="1" data-x="0" class="ui-state-default  ui-selectee"></span>
<span data-y="2" data-x="0" class="ui-state-default  ui-selectee"></span>
<span data-y="3" data-x="0" class="ui-state-default  ui-selectee"></span>
<span data-y="4" data-x="0" class="ui-state-default  ui-selectee"></span>
<span data-y="5" data-x="0" class="ui-state-default  ui-selectee"></span>
```

Now when I  click on seletable I want to know elements on which click event happens. WHen I try to get with these code I am getting (parent div)

```
stop: function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(event.target);
}
```

How to get clicked span in jquery seletable.

Comment: why don't you use the [selected](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected) event http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y8vWA/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is to use the [selected event](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected)

```
selected: function (event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.selected);
},
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y8vWA/)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
console.log(event.relatedTarget);
```

Comment: on which element is the event set? Try to set it on children of timeslot.

Comment: I don't think it will work as `stop` is not a triggered from an element see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y8vWA/2/

Comment: `$('#timeslot').children().click(function( event,) {
    console.log(event.target);
})`

Answer (score 0):

Try [event.relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.relatedTarget)

```
stop: function (event, ui) {
    console.log(event.relatedTarget);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[event.currentTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WRSM4/)

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({
    selected: function( event, ui ) {
        alert($(ui.selected).data('y'));
    }
});
```

**REFERENCE**

selected : http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected